# Android Up Navigation and Button in Action Bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, up-navigation

I have an action bar that looks like so:

[image: Action Bar]

I am using the following to see which button is clicked:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
            case R.id.view_all_trains:
                Intent i = new Intent(ToStationActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

    }
    return true;
}
```

No matter what button you press, (the back or the pin), it goes back to the previous screen and I am not sure why. Any suggestions as to why this may happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `break` statement at the end of each case of the switch!

Answer (score 1):

You need to finish the case at the end using `break;`, else the control flow continues at the next case.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.view_all_trains:
            Intent i = new Intent(ToStationActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            break;
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

    }
    return true;
}
```